# Why does the edit summary have an appended whitespace in some places?

Tags: bug, timeline, edit-summary

The edit summary is appended with a whitespace character in the user profile's revision list.

[image: screenshot profile's revision list]

When I've needed to copy-paste an edit summary I've ended up taking the extra work to not select the whitespace. But later I realised that entering a trailing whitespace in the edit summary causes it to be trimmed and it's only shown in the user's revision list and in the [post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline).

[image: screenshot posts's revision history]

Unless there's some practical need to keep the whitespace I think it should be removed because text selection is more accurate without the trailing whitespace and it would minimize potential confusion for the user.

Also interesting to note that in the edit history of a post system generated edit summaries don't have the trailing whitespace only user entered edit summaries have the whitespace.

[image: screenshot post's edit history]

Comment: Yes, both leading and trailing space could be automatically removed on submit (presuming that is the reason).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be user-generated.

Using me as an example (the first of the two bottom screenshots), my phone auto-completed "minimum " followed by a space. [There! It did it again!].

Compare that with [one of mine that I finished with a fullstop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359358/revisions), which my phone does not follow with a space:

On neither my user profile:

[image]

Nor the post's edit history:

[image]

Comment: The full stop does play a role in it because the edit history doesn't have the trailing whitespace, however the trailing whitespace is in the [User Profile revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/906208/rick?tab=activity&sort=revisions) for that same post. So it would seem the whitespace depends on using a full stop (which is rendered differently depending on site element), not on the device used in editing.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't see it on my profile - as per my edit

Comment: It's possible your phone doesn't select trailing whitspaces... A better way would be checking the source code to see if the whitespace is there, unless I'm mistaken it's in the HTML (although it's followed by half a dozen closing `div`s so it's not easy to check either).